# Core dumped while performing linked list operation in "CodePad" (which is an online C++ compiler)

Tags: c++, linked-list, coredump, unordered-set

Recently I have been practising some linked list coding questions. I just started using unordered_set. The question is, "Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list". I have used unordered_set for this. But I'm having the problem of "coredump" when I try to initialize the linked list.

It displays the array when I comment out the last 3 lines of populateList. It displays core dumped when ever I try to access head in populateList.

This is the entire code I have written. I have written this in codepad website.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>

#include<unordered_set>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
Node *head=NULL;
void populateList(Node *head)
{
    int arr[]={7,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,5,7,3,9,3,7,3,6,2,5,7,4};
    cout<<"\n\n";
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    Node *ptr=head;
```

If I comment out the content in the for loop below everything runs smoothly.

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ptr->data=arr[i];
        ptr->next=NULL;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Node *ptr=head, *prev=head;
    populateList(head);
    unordered_set<int> A;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(A.find(ptr->data)==A.end())
        {
            A.insert(ptr->data);
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next=ptr->next;    
            delete ptr;
            ptr=prev->next;
        }
        prev=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr=head;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a suspicious lack of `new` in that code.

Comment: You call `populateList(head)` where `head == NULL`, then go right ahead and dereference this `NULL` pointer with `head->data = ...;`

Comment: Putting the content of previous comments into other words: you are not allocating the nodes of list using operator `new`.

Comment: *But I'm having the problem of "coredump"* -- In other words, your program has bugs.  I think it's time to use the debugger and learn how programmers solve these problems (instead of just writing code, seeing it doesn't work, and have SO contributors debug the code you wrote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your for loop you set next to NULL then try to dereference it on next iteratation

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    ptr->data=arr[i];
    ptr->next=NULL; // now ptr->next is NULL
    ptr=ptr->next; // ptr = ptr->next = NULL;
}
```

if you unroll this

```
int i = 0;
ptr->data=arr[0];
ptr->next=NULL;
ptr=ptr->next; // ptr = ptr->next = NULL;
i++;
// because we set ptr to NULL this is dereferencing the NULL pointer
ptr->data=array[1];
...
```